# How do I create canonical meta tags for mutli-lingual websites to improve SEO?

Tags: asp.net, localization, metadata, multilingual, canonical-link

I have a company website (Visual Studio / VB / ASP.NET 4.0) and it's now localized in 10 different languages.

The problem:  My URLs do NOT change when switching from, say, English to Swedish.  Only the text changes, as it calls the information from the "sv" resource file instead of the "en" resource file.  [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/896341/stefan)  noted that this will not count against me for duplicate content.

But [Tiggerito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303484/tiggerito) came up with an excellent suggestion.  He suggested I use canonical tags in the  section to intimate to SE bots that I have other languages.  I'd like to follow his suggestion, and **add canonical tags to my master pages**.

Can anybody tell me how I can go about doing this?  What would the tags look like, and would I have to have one for en, es-MX, ru, sv, fr, etc.?  Thanks for any guidance you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all its not good SEO to have the same page, same url, with totally different content. You confuse the search engines that do not know what to show. What search machine index to show ? what language of all. This is not count as duplicate content but indexer see you like to change the page and the language too often and do not what to show.

Second, the canonical tag works only for google from what I know, and second its not take language as an argument. The canonical tag works the different way connect many different url with similar content to the one url, not split one url to many different contents.

Is better to have you home page your default language, and when you change language to change the url, or add a url parameter.

Here is a canonical tag.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/page.html"/>
```

About canonical tags
http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/canonical-link-tag/
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html

### Notes

In this url that @JasonWeber give me

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html

say it very clear: 
**if you’re going to localize, make it visible in the search results**
and 
**"And last but not least, keep the content for each language on separate URLs - don't use cookies to show translated versions."**

Comment: Aristos, thank you for replying.  Stefan noted that in http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html that it's fine to have the same URL in different languages, and Google recommends creating canonical tags to let the googlebot know.  I don't know how to add a parameter or a URL without completely revamping my website.  Is this easy to do?

Comment: @JasonWeber I read now this link, and my question is simple: Is google the only search engine in the world ?

Comment: @JasonWeber Even in the url you give say very clear "And last but not least, keep the content for each language on separate URLs - don't use cookies to show translated versions."

Comment: Thank you Aristos.  I think your advice is good advice.  In fact, since it's an entirely different question, I posted a new question and referenced your name, in appreciation for your help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050272/i-have-a-multilingual-website-how-do-i-add-parameters-or-a-url-without-too-much ... thank you very much, Aristos, I am going to work on your solution all night tonight until I get it to work!  Much appreciated!